# Unable to print array when trying to fork multiple ping request in PERL

Tags: perl

I am trying to ping 2 IP's using `fork` in PERL. I am pushing IP's that are reachable and non reachable in different arrays. At the end of program I am printing arrays but i am not getting output

Below is the code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my (@up, @down, @child, @test);

sub prog1 {
    my $ip = $_[0];
    print "Started testing IP : $ip \n";
    my $resp = `ping $ip`;
    if ( $resp =~ /reply/) {
        push (@up, $ip);
    }
    else {
        push (@down, $ip);
    }
    push (@test, $ip);
    print "Ended with testing of ip $ip \n";
}

my @list = qw /192.168.1.1 192.168.2.1/;
foreach (@list) {
    my $pid = fork();
    if ( !$pid ) {
        prog1($_);
        exit 0;
    }
    else {
        push (@child, $pid);
    }
}

foreach (@child) {
    waitpid ($_, 0);
    print "Done with pid $_ \n";
}

print "\n\n up is @up";
print "\n\n down is @down\n";
print "test is @test";
```

Output i am getting is

```
$ perl fork_ping.pl
Started testing IP : 192.168.1.1
Started testing IP : 192.168.2.1
Ended with testing of ip 192.168.1.1
Done with pid 99804
Ended with testing of ip 192.168.2.1
Done with pid 81456


 up is

 down is
test is
```

As you can see `@up` and `@down` arrays are empty. Any clue why it is not populating any IP there

Comment: Forks don't share variables with parent.

Comment: @mpapec: How to print arrays then

Comment: Don't fork is the easiest way.  If you must fork, you need to set up a mechanism, perhaps a pipe, that allows the children to communicate with the parent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Can u give me a demo code here or provide me any link that can help

Comment: why you need fork? because if you fork only because want ping large number of hosts - check [AnyEvent::FastPing](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::FastPing)

Comment: @jm666: M learning fork. So just took a problem and written a small code. M just curious to learn how to communicate between child and parent

Comment: @Nitesh You now know, how to fork. You already know, the the fork starts a new process. You want communicate between two processes. In this case the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Yourself) manpage is the best staring point...